# Ударения в поэтической речи начала ХХ века

Tags: орфоэпия, поэзия

Читая [бальмонтовский перевод "Жизни Будды"](http://royallib.com/book/ashvaghosha/gizn_buddi.html), заметил, что некоторые ударения там расставлены несколько необычно. Если в части бальмонтовских неологизмов или слов, известных мне только по письменной речи, разночтения понятны, то ударное **или́** с ударением на втором "и" всё-таки удивляет: Бальмонт - достаточно серьёзный поэт, чтобы позволять себе подгонять ударение под размер (да ещё и в нерифмованной стопе, где возможности выстраивать ритм и так многочисленны).

У меня есть несколько возможных объяснений (кроме вариантов с подвижным ударением, двойной нормой и так далее):

1) в поэтической речи допустим / допускался сдвиг ударения в синтагме;

2) сдвиг ударений имеет иную причину (какую?)

Вот слова и словоформы, ударение в которых вызывает вопросы (тут могут быть и слова, правильное ударение в которых мне неизвестно, поскольку в разговорном языке они обычно не употребляются). Я выделяю несколько групп таких слов:

***1) краткие прилагательные и причастия:***

си́лен (краткая форма от "сильный")

(он был) замкну́т (в себе)

ю́ны

уто́нчен; воздушно-уто́нчен

те и на́ги, и мохнаты

(их души) пу́сты

(в различении) то́чны

(эти основы) глубо́ки

***2) односложные существительные (преимущественно - мужского рода):***

(четыре эти) бе́ды

яды́

хо́ды

от плод'а

(обратил) бесо́в

***3) глаголы (главным образом архаизмы):***

обо́дриться

спиля́т

у́зрю; (едва такую сладость) у́зрят; (если ясно) у́зришь

пре́зрел (= "отринул")

милова́л (= "ласкал")

***4) союзы:***

дабы́ (также отмечено ударное "бы" в синтагме)
или́

***5) два существительных:***

с пе́тлею

(не подвижник он, а) ми́ряни́н

Что здесь архаика, а что - поэтическая инновация (если есть)?

Comment: Очень сложно понять, в чём же суть вопроса?

Comment: Что здесь архаика, а что - поэтическая инновация (если есть)? И откуда такие ударения?